# Why is this htaccess rule assigning two matches to one $_GET variable?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

Here's the htaccess rule for my site's profile page:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/?(.+)?/?(.+)? profile.php?id=$1&slug=$2&tab=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

When you click on a tab on a user's profile, such as **favorites**:

> /users/83028/nathan-johnson/favorites

The `$_GET` variable with the name of *slug* is receiving `nathan-johnson/favorites` instead of just `nathan-johnson` and the `tab` variable is blank, according to a `var_dump`:

```
array(3) { 
      ["id"]=> string(5) "83028" 
      ["slug"]=> string(24) "nathan-johnson/favorites" 
      ["tab"]=> string(0) "" }
```

It looks like the issue is with my htaccess regexp (above), but I don't see the issue with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not positive what ?(.+)? is supposed to do but I generally use ([^/]*)in replace of it when I do similiar things

Comment: @JohnB The `?`'s makes the match before it _optional_ so it isn't required to be there to make the rule work. And `.` matches any character (the `+` means as many characters as needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your forward slashes are optional (via `/?`), the `(.+)` grouping is greedy and will gobble them all up. You need to make them non-greedy by adding a **?**:  (.+?)

Also, instead of `(.+)?` you should just use a `*` which means none, one, or more.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/?([^/]*)/?(.*?)?$ profile.php?id=$1&slug=$2&tab=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Also, instead of using `%{QUERY_STRING}`, you can just use the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/?([^/]*)/?(.*?)?$ profile.php?id=$1&slug=$2&tab=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't seem to work, the `slug` and `tab` variables both don't have values now: `array(3) { ["id"]=> string(5) "83028" ["slug"]=> string(0) "" ["tab"]=> string(0) "" }` Any ideas?

Comment: @Nathan Sorry, didn't see what you were trying to do exactly. There's a few things missing from the regular expression, you need the `$` at the end so that the non-greedy match gets everything. Then you need to replace the middle path with `([^/]*)` to ensure that the last non-greedy doesn't gobble it up